# How to break string through regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, split

String:

```
"hello, how are you? you are fine. i am good too."
```

I want to break this string on the basis of `, ? .` these characters in php through reg-ex or you can provide me simple reg-ex.

Desired result in an array:

```
[0]hello 
[1]how are you 
[2]you are fine 
[3]i am good too
```

Please provide regex for this. again the question is that provide the regex through which i can break the string. Matching characters should be `. , ?`

Comment: Rather than *Please provide regex for this*, SO users would be more likely to help if you can show some prior attempts and then help - at the moment it's more a case of asking others to do it for you.

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with this regex:

```
/[^A-Za-z\s]\s*/
```

It looks for a character which is not a letter or whitespace, followed optionally by one or more spaces. This allows for the situation where there is no space after the punctuation mark. Note we use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag to `preg_split` so that if the string ends in a punctuation mark we don't get empty strings in the output.

```
$string = "hello, how are you?you are fine. i am good too.";
$output = preg_split('/[^A-Za-z\s]\s*/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => hello
    [1] => how are you
    [2] => you are fine
    [3] => i am good too 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/g4s61)

Comment: I didn't know about the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`! Thanks. This simplifies a lot the after treatment of removing empty elements

Comment: @Allan it can save a lot of code. You just have to be really careful to remember to include the `limit` parameter (`-1` in my example) as well...

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `preg_split` method with a regex that matches any non-word character followed by a space and a non-word character at the end of the text.
The `if` is used to `pop` the ending empty string present in the array if your input text does contain a punctuation character at the very end of it.

```
$input = "hello, how are you? you are fine. i am good too.";
$output = preg_split( "/\W(?:\s|$)/", $input );

if(strlen(end($output))==0)
{
   array_pop($output);
}

foreach ($output as $item) {
    echo $item;
    echo "\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
hello
how are you
you are fine
i am good too
```